# Communicate between C# IIS hosted website and C# windows service on same machine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ipc, named-pipes

I'm looking for the simplest way of communicating between

1. A website with its logic written in C# and hosted in IIS
2. A C# windows service that is going to handle the long running operations
   from the website

They're both on the same machine. I've worked with WCF services hosted in a windows service before but I think WCF isn't being worked on or improved anymore?

Ideally the communication will be as simple as calling a C# method, without having to worry about JSON/XML serialization and deserialization and it won't have all the overhead of a WCF service.

Other methods of communicating I've found online are

- Sockets - I can't find a way for it to continuously listen on a TCP port without spinning in an infinite loop.
- Named pipes - looks promising but I haven't worked with them before so it's hard to evaluate
- Inter process communication. Still not sure what this is other than a catch all term for generic ways of communication outside of a process, like a shared text file.

Comment: WCF is most definitely alive and well, and the current .NET implementatoin of SOAP services.  Web API is REST-based (though you can do REST with WCF as well).   WCF gives you flexibility in terms of communication protocols, whereas Web API is HTTP only.  In terms of your scenario, WCF with net named pipes is probably the best mechanism, though if the task is truly long running you may want to use oneway operations (i..e, fire and forget).

Comment: Also consider what you want to do if the Windows Service isn't running when you need to talk to it. It might be that a message queue (possibly using WCF - it has good support for MSMQ) is a better fit.

Comment: However, it's hard to know what to recommend without knowing what sort of performance, reliability, ease of implementation, transactionality, etc you require.